# pixelsearch and click right pixel

Tags: autohotkey

```
IF NOT A_IsAdmin ; Runs script as Admin.
{
   Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
   ExitApp
}

#MaxThreadsPerHotkey, 2
CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
#singleInstance, Force
toggle = 0


upperLeftX := 750
upperLeftY := 400
lowerRightX := 850
lowerRightY := 500

F8::  ; press F8 to toggle the loop on/off.
SoundBeep
Toggle := !Toggle
While Toggle
{ ;-- Begin of loop.

PixelSearch, X, Y,%upperLeftX%, %upperLeftY%, %lowerRightX%, %lowerRightY%, 0x000000, 0, Fast RGB



IF ErrorLevel = 1   ; IF NOTFound.  
{
sleep, 100
}

IF ErrorLevel = 0   ; IF Found. 
{ 

MouseClick, left                        
sleep, 300
}

} ;-- End of Loop.
return
```

F8 starts loop and this code checks specific pixel in rectangle and sends left click.

It works with `[MouseClick, left, %X%, %Y%]`.But I want to know how can I use *dllcall mouse event* to click on specific pixel.

for example

`DllCall("mouse_event",uint,1,int,%X%,int,%Y%,uint,0,int,0)`

But its not working

Comment: could you please elaborate your question? if you want to click on a pixel, you already provided the solution for it `MouseClick, left, %X%, %Y%`

Comment: DllCall("mouse_event",uint,1,int,%X%,int,%Y%,uint,0,int,0)   I want to use something like this.

Comment: why? whats the point of it? - maybe `sendMessage` is of interest for you (i've barely used/known it) if a simple `send` doesn't fit your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you actually want to do this via DLL calls. mouse_event doesn't even take coordinates, but values between 0-65535.
If you want to be able to click any pixel on the screen make sure you set it to be relative to the screen: `CoordMode, Mouse, Screen`

Then use `ControlClick`/`PostMessage`/`SendMessage` if you don't want to affect your mouse pointer by that click. Or use `MouseClick`/`Click`. Or `MouseMove+Send, {LButton}`.